# DS1102E oscilloscope not triggering above 200mV

Tags: oscilloscope, trigger

Once adjusting the vertical scale of my Rigol DS1102E oscilloscope from 200mV to 500mV the signal appears to be lost. Instead of showing the "T'D" (triggered) icon in the top left it then shows "AUTO". This occurs on both ch1 and ch2.

500 mV scale:
[image]

200 mV scale:
[image]

<sub>Original pictures: https://imgur.com/a/f4uWI4x</sub>

Comment: Scope shots at 200 mV and 500 mV scale showing the problem would be useful.

Comment: Done! Top image is 500, bottom is 200

Comment: Strange.  Your zero level seems off too.  Does your scope have a calibration routine you can run? I'd try that first.  If that doesn't help it may be time to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Does it has the same issue on both channel 1 and 2?

Comment: What are the settings for the channel and trigger?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, run the self test and self cal. These should be run about once a year for every scopes (especially higher ends model). I'm expecting it to fail both the self test and self cal. If so, you might need to attempt repair or replace the unit.

If they don't fail, your issue will most likely be resolved.

I don't know how the front end of this scope is designed. If you are lucky, it will be mostly in replaceable components and you might be able to find the defective part. I'd expect either to be a blown resistor or a defective MUX but it could also be an amplifier or a power supply issue.

Comment: I'm just going to go with this conclusion. After calibrating it did other funky stuff and it's basically different every time you start it up. I'm going to assume there's a component broken. Given that it's a pretty old one with little to no maintenance.

Comment: Yeah, that is typical. If you are using it professionally, I would replace it and not even try to repair it. If it was my own, I would attempt a repair. In both case, I wouldn't trust it until it fully pass it's cal and self test.

Comment: Another 'scope manufacturer requires a loooong warmup before doing a "cal" procedure. Needs it about 4 times a year (seasonal?). Afterwards,  zero offset aligns with its marker, improves trigger level too, and its measurement functions. But doesn't improve the occasional hard-reset.

Comment: Just like the ACAL of your DMM, every the more often the better. By experience, most scope I have seen and used didn't have the self cal done for years. regarding temperature, scope aren't as much affected by thermal drift as many equipment. Lower frequencies oscilloscope, like this one, don't really have a significant thermal drift, so I wouldn't worry about warmup time.  If you want to play safe, 1 hour is plenty for any modern oscilloscope (even if the recommendation is 4 hours).